# UITabBarController icons display incorrectly

Tags: ios, icons, tabbar

I am building a universal `iOS` App. I have 5 icons on the `UITabBarController` and two of them are displayed incorrectly. They are higher on the `UITabBarController` than the rest of the icons. I can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: you create tabBar in storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski I created them is storyboard

Comment: Can you show this storyboard then ?

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski I uploaded the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:**

Select your `Tab Bar Item` in the storyboard.

[image]

**Second:**

Set the insets you want:

[image]

## **Sidenote:** (Probably your actual problem)

Make sure your images are correct size in `pixels` before adding it to your project, to avoid taking up to much space and have the images sticking outside the `UITabBar`. All your icons should have the exact same height/width when you add them to the project.

Comment: Thank you! My assets all had an exact same size in pixels, but changing image inset helped!

Comment: @DariaAgadzhanova Glad to help :) don't forget to mark as answer when possible if this solved the problem.